# Over-riding bootstrap template CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap template that has a stylesheet called styles.css. I want to modify the following class in styles.css

```
.contact {
    background-color: #56bc94;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 80px 0;
}
```

I created a common.css that I place after styles.css and added the following

```
.contact {
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   padding: 80px 0;
}
```

However, it's not over-riding the styles.css class. I tried with !important as well, but doesn't work.

```
.contact {
  background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
  padding: 80px 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `common.css` has loaded?

Comment: I guess you need to check if common.css has loaded properly. Have you provided the link??

Answer (score 1):

In `common.css` use:

```
@import url("styles.css");
.contact {background-color: #f5f5f5; padding: 80px 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this forces both the css to load. I figured in my case,it was an issue with the browser cache. Once I cleared the cache,it worked fine.